# iAd not fitting on iPad ladscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to fit iAd also in both modes, landscape and portrait but not able to reach it in landscape mode, banner keeps at same ratio. Thank you, here is my code:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateOn" context:NULL];
        adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -adView.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;

    }

}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateOff" context:NULL];
        adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, adView.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }

}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    } else {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;

    adView =[[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;

    adView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:adView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this [official Apple link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html) you can find the code you are looking for.

In that document there is a section called: Changing the Banner Size Dynamically

On that section Apple specifically says that in order to be able to change the size of the banner dynamically you need this line of code:

```
self.bannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: 
           ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, 
                  ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];
```

I haven't seen it on the code you posted.